# More efficient creation of XML file than SQL Server FOR EXPLICIT

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, optimization, ssis

I have a set of SQL procedures in SQL Server 2008 R2, which ultimately produce a large XML file, which is collected by SSIS and saved to an ftp folder for a customer. Everything works fine for relatively small data sets, but the performance is prohibitively bad for large sets; I need to make things quicker if I can.

Here is a summary of the current steps that are taken each time the xml is produced (all steps are called by the SSIS package which eventually takes the xml back and saves it):

1. Data Collected from Live database into my database
2. Data transformed into another table (called Proto_XML), so it has the structure required for `FOR XML EXPLICIT` to work (with column names like `[ParentName!2!TagName!ELEMENT]`, lots of repeated data, lots of nulls, and tag and parent ids at each row, but indexes on all columns that are later used to order the results).
3. `SELECT * FROM Proto_XML ORDER BY... FOR XML EXPLICIT` query performed on Proto_XML table to make an xml file.
4. About 12 xquery lines are run on the xml to clean it up. They mostly look like this sort of thing: `SET @XML.modify('delete //Data31/*//*[empty(.//text())]')`. I wish I could avoid this step, especially since it involves using untyped XML, but have found no way to create XML without empty elements in at least some places.
5. Attempt to validate the xml against a schema; if it succeeds, return the xml. I have avoided actually applying the schema to the xml as doing so converts the formatted numbers to their cannonical values.

I have looked at lots of information about how it might be possible to speed up the last three steps, which are all in the same procedure(for a large file, it took over 6 hours!). I have not been able to see how I can apply any of these suggestions in this case, however; given the size and complexity of the XML, I really don't think that I will be able to use `FOR XML AUTO` or `FOR XML RAW` as some sites suggest. There are also various suggestions to improve the speed of `FOR XML EXPLICIT` transformations, but I can't see how I can make things any easier for `FOR XML EXPLICIT` than making it refer directly to a correctly formatted, indexed table as I currently do.

A possible solution was suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941699/for-xml-and-performance), but I have not found any advice on how to convert a Full Result Set into an xml file within SSIS (presumably using a Script Task), if that is what the answer means. There was also a decision early in the project to avoid using a Script Task for the job in the (incorrect?) belief that this would be even slower than SQL.

My question, then, is this - what would you recommend to try in order to see about speeding the creation of the xml file - should I use something other than SQL Server for this step and if so, do you have any ideas about what I should be using / any keywords or links that I can use to find out how to achieve the xml creation?

this is the meat of what the `FOR XML EXPLICIT` procedure that takes so long looks like (all names have been removed):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results

DECLARE @SchemaError NVARCHAR(1000)

CREATE TABLE #Results
( Value XML NOT NULL)

DECLARE
     @AvailableFields   VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    ,@OrderBy           VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@SQL               VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    ,@Untyped_XML       XML
    ,@XML               XML(DataFeed_Schema)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- We should attempt to select all fields from the available data table, unless restricted in the formatting of
-- the datafeed itself.
SELECT
    @AvailableFields = @AvailableFields + QUOTENAME(Col.name) + ','
FROM
    MyDataBase.sys.columns  AS Col
WHERE
    Col.object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyDataBase.dbo.Proto_XML')
-- ignore the identity column; we only want the ones that actually go in the XML, starting with "Tag"
AND Col.name <> 'Id'
ORDER BY
    Col.column_id

SELECT @AvailableFields = LEFT(@AvailableFields,LEN(@AvailableFields)-1)

SELECT @OrderBy = '
         [Level4!4!Name!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data6!6!Label!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data10!10!Name!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data12!12!Label!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data16!16!Name!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data18!18!Label!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data22!22!Number!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data23!23!Name!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data25!25!Name!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data29!29!Name!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data31!31!CreateDate!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data32!32!LastName!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data34!34!Label!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data37!37!Label!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data39!39]
        ,[Data40!40!Name!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data42!42!CreateDate!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data46!46!Id!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data48!48!Id!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data50!50!Id!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data53!53!Id!ELEMENT]
        ,[Data54!54]
        ,[Data55!55!Type!ELEMENT]
        ,Tag
        ,Parent'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Use our list of columns to select what we want into our temporary table (the table is just used so that a
-- variable can be referenced in the dynamic sql and in the main query).
SELECT @SQL =
'INSERT #Results(Value)
SELECT
    (SELECT ' + @AvailableFields + '
     FROM Proto_XML
     ORDER BY' + @OrderBy + '
     FOR XML EXPLICIT
    )'

PRINT (@SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)

-- Pop our newly created XML into a variable ready for its spring clean.
SELECT @Untyped_XML = Value FROM #Results

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Delete all empty nodes below the __ Level
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Data31/*//*[empty(.//text())]')
-- Delete all empty nodes exactly one level below __ (This will leave the parent, but will not affect those
-- more levels below (e.g will not delete the empty parents left below __)
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Data22/*/*[empty(.//text())]')
-- do the same below __, __ and __
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Data54/*[empty(.//text())]')
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Data48/*[empty(.//text())]')
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Data46/*[empty(.//text())]')
-- We use "_" to indicate an empty label, so that the line above does not delete the parent __ level
-- from __. Now that we have done the step above, we can delete the __ that are so marked.
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Data29/Data33/Data34[. = "_"]')
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //ClaimantInfo/CustomFields/CustomField[. = "_"]')
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Claim/CoverStatus/PurposeOfTrip[. = "_"]')
-- Delete all empty __, __ and __ empty custom fields.
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Data12/CustomFields/*[empty(.//text())]')
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Data10/CustomFields/*[empty(.//text())]')
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('delete //Data4/CustomFields/*[empty(.//text())]')
-- There are some mandatory fields - if these have empty indicators, they need to be emptied.
SET @Untyped_XML.modify('replace value of (//Data31/Data32[text() = "_"]/text())[1] with ""')
-- Add version and NameSpace information
SELECT @Untyped_XML = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@Untyped_XML),'<DataFeed>','<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<DataFeed xmlns ="http://tempuri.org/MyData.xsd">')
-- See if we can get the XML into the schema...
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @XML = @UNTYPED_XML
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @SchemaError =  ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH

IF @SchemaError IS NULL
    SELECT @Untyped_XML AS DataFeedContent
ELSE
    SELECT @SchemaError AS 'ErrorEncountered', @Untyped_XML AS FailedXML

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE #Results
```

Comment: Look at [`FOR XML PATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx) - much simpler and yet more powerful than the `FOR XML EXPLICIT` stuff..

Comment: I have not managed to recreate the complexity of my XML with `FOR XML PATH`. There are two possible reasons for this - 'FOR XML PATH` is limited, or I need to do more learning. I will gladly try to learn more, but is it definitely capable of producing complex and customised bits of XML? I only question because I have tried and failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using an XML task in SSIS and transforming the XML using an XSLT transform.  I've done that in the past when I wanted to introduce CDATA sections (due to a customer requirement), since FOR XML EXPLICIT looked like so very much work.

I'm curious as to what part of the final three steps takes the longest.  Can you profile your stored procedure and see which lines in your procedure are taking up the highest percentage of time?

Comment: Hi @Ann, I'll check out the proc and post the results here. With ref to your answer, do you mean that I should use 'FOR XML PATH' or something in SQL Server to make some fast, nasty XML, then give that to the package and convert it into nice XML there using a stylesheet? Or is there a way to convert a full result set into XML in SSIS?

Comment: Ok, so looking at the actual execution plan of the procedure, it turns out that the xquery `modify` commands are all taking 12% of the batch cost each. This adds up to basically 100% of the cost of the batch...  Unfortunately, these modify commands are required to fit the xml into a schema, so I can't make the file typed XML before the commands are run.

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter My idea was that you achieve the same effect as your `modify` commands by use of a stylesheet.  But you could go further and generate some simpler XML and turn it into what you need with the stylesheet.  (You could even chain the XML tasks and apply several stylesheets in a row.)

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter Incidentally, if you have access to Profiler, I'd have that running (filtered way down so you only capture this one proc) and see what command it says takes up the most time.  The execution plan can be extremely helpful, but it doesn't always reflect the actual run time.

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter ... and actually, I notice you have 12 `modify` statements.  12 x 12% is 144% ... something looks wrong there!

Comment: I ran the Profiler and it is clear that the `For XML Explicit` part is not even close to the slowest bit of this query. Here are some of the durations: `FOR XML EXPLICIT`: 1278, `Modify`: 58903, 'Modify':182477, `Modify`: 6356 ... and so on. I see your point very well made about doing the modifications somewhere else, with a stylesheet.